# Xilinx ISE Post Place and route simulation using behavioral modules

Tags: simulation, verilog

I have created a verilog module A, and a testbench for this module called A_tb.

The testbench contains instances of other modules (B,C) that are connected to an instance of A in the testbench.

I can correctly generate post synthesis timings for A, and want to run a post PnR simulation using testbench A_tb.

Running a behavioral simulation on the testbench works, and produces correct results.

Running a post-PnR simulation gives an error that modules B,C can't be found. Is it possible to simulate these modules behavioral-ly just to generate stimulus for the post PnR timings model of A ?

EDIT: Synthesis and post-PnR timing using XST, simulation using isim.

Comment: How and where are you setting `$sdf_annotate`?, you might have the wrong scope selected

Comment: I don't know what $sdf_annotate is, am looking it up.

Comment: `$sdf_annotate` is for applying post-PnR timing information to the simulation. When I saw post-PnR I accidentally assumed it was a timing annotation related problem. It can generate a similar error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run simulations with the same B/C modules in both cases.

For your behavioral simulation that works, are modules A, B and C all in the same file?  If so, you should split modules B and C out into a separate file from module A, then load in the new file with modules B and C.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have the modules split in separate files.

Comment: Through the IDE. I have selected the A module as top-level in the implementation flow. I then switch to the simulation flow, select the A_tb, switch to post-PnR, and click simulate. A is synthesized, the timing model is generated and isim correctly uses this model for A. The problem is B and C, where it says "B_instance instantiated from unknown module"

Comment: This is not a Verilog coding issue.  You need to get help on using your IDE from the vendor.